# Multiple AJAX calls may or may not be called then execute function

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, razor

I'm using C# and jQuery to build a form page and I have multiple inputs and if they are filled I'd like to submit an AJAX call to the attached SQL Server, if they are not filled I'd like to do nothing.
Once all the filled ones have their AJAX calls complete then I'd like to reload the page.

Right now I have a function like this:

```
Func1()
{
   if ($'#form1').val().length > 0 {
   $.post('https://foo/', {id: id, column: col1, value: $('form1').val())
   }

   if ($'#form2').val().length > 0 {
   $.post('https://foo/', {id: id, column: col1, value: $('form2').val())
   }
}

$('#submit').click(function() {
  Func1();
  window.location.reload(true);
} );
```

However this leads to some values being updated but not all, which I know has to do with my async calls. I'm fairly new to async calls, but normally I'd put a .then(function(){}); on the end of them, and they work fine but in this case it doesn't fix anything. Can someone point me in the right direction of resources to fix this? I can't nest my AJAX call because sometimes 2 will be updated and 1 will not.

Comment: Why the 'C#' and 'razor' tags? I guess you're using them on your project, but they don't seem to have anything to do with the question. Anyway, if you want to reload the page after all the Ajax calls complete you can use `Promise.all()` to wait for them.

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes I am using them both for my project. Sorry if they are not relevant, I wasn't sure. Can you give me more context about how Promise.all() would be used?

Comment: Yes, its because ajax is async and you call `location.reload()` before the ajax calls have been complete. But the whole purpose of ajax is to stay on the same page and to use `location.reload()` after an ajax call is utterly pointless (and is degrading performance)

Comment: Added some info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirements, you could acheive it by minor reorg of the code:

```
  function form1CallAsync(){
      var d = $.Deferred();
      if ($'#form1').val().length > 0) {
       // Ajax call for Form1 post. Important: In the success callback, have    
       //d.resolve() in the end, in the error callback, d.reject()
      } else { d.resolve(); }
      return d.promise();
    }
    function form2CallAsync(){
      var d = $.Deferred();
      if ($'#form2').val().length > 0) {
       // Ajax call for Form2 post. Important: In the success callback, have    
       //d.resolve() in the end, in the error callback, d.reject()
      } else { d.resolve(); }
      return d.promise();
    }
    $('#submit').click(function() {   
           $.when(form1CallAsync(), form2CallAsync()).done(
                  function(a1, a2){
                       // your code to process the results from both ajax posts
                       // ..
                       window.location.reload(true);
                  }
           )
     });
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! I'm going to try it out then mark it as the answer if it works.

Comment: This worked great, you just need to actually call the functions after .$when with constructor brackets.

Comment: You also need to resolve the deferred in the else statement of each function

Answer (score 0):

I can think of one solution. There may be better solutions.

1) Declare two boolean variables with false.

2) Set each variable true once that particular call is success/fail.

3) Move window reload to document ready and reload accordingly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
  if (callOne == true && calltwo == true){
 window.location.reload(true);
 }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the elegant   [jQuery When](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

Using above, could rewrite your code as:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
   if (($'#form1').val().length > 0 && ($'#form2').val().length > 0) {
       $.when($.post(*form1Call*), $.post(*form2Call*)).done(
              function(a1, a2){
                   // your code to process the results from both ajax posts
                   // ..
                   window.location.reload(true);
              }
       )
   }      
 });
```

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, this wouldn't solve my problem if form2 was filled out but form1 wasn't, it would never submit the updates for form2.